# For loop c# only prints the last element of loop in windows form

Tags: c#

I am making a Windows Form app in C#. I need to print an array with random numbers on the screen.

[image]

There are 20 numbers in total (0 till 19). But it only prints the 19th element. Can anyone help me out? (See image) Don't worry about the comparison number. I just want to print all arrays in the label in the form. Here is some code:

```
const int numberOfItems = 20;
   
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-US");
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;

    int[] numbers = new int[numberOfItems];

    Random random = new Random();
    double total = 0;
          
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        numbers[i] = random.Next(501);  
        beforeLoop.Text = $"Element {i} = {numbers[i]}";
        total += numbers[i];
    }
}

private void compare_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int[] numbers = new int[numberOfItems];

    Random random = new Random();
    double total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        numbers[i] = random.Next(501);
              
        int numberBigger = numbers[i] + 10;
        int numberSmaller = numbers[i] - 5;
        total += numbers[i];
        int number = int.Parse(numberBox.Text);

        if (number > numbers[i])
        {
            printLabel.Text = $"Element {i} = {numberBigger}";
        }
        else
        {
            printLabel.Text = $"Element {i} = {numberSmaller}";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You repeatedly assign values to `beforeLoop.Text`. Since your computer is probably quite fast, shouldn't it be obvious that you will only see the result of the final assignment?

Comment: You're currently reassigning the `Text` Property which is overwriting any previously set values. Try using "+=" instead of just "=" and see if that works. You may also need a "new line" character (try `System.Environment.NewLine`) at the end to put each "Element" on its own line.

Comment: For future questions please re-read [mre] guidance on posting code. There is really no need to all "generate random" part, or whole `compare_Click` method. Ideally even removing `for` loop and replacing it with two assignments like `string s = "a"; s = "b";`  and question like "where 'a' goes after the second assignment".

Comment: You are just assigning one value at a time to the textbox wuth `beforeLoop.Text = $"Element {i} = {numbers[i]}";`. Did you want to use a multiline textbox, or a listbox or some other control to display multiple lines of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question, I understand that you want to concatenate the strings and print them in **multiline** label control. If so, then try this code:

```cs
const int numberOfItems = 20;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-US");
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;

    int[] numbers = new int[numberOfItems];

    Random random = new Random();
    double total = 0;
   
    var text = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        numbers[i] = random.Next(501);
        
        text += $"Element {i} = {numbers[i]} \n";
        total += numbers[i];
    }

    beforeLoop.Text = text;
}

private void compare_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    int[] numbers = new int[numberOfItems];

    Random random = new Random();
    double total = 0;
    var text = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        numbers[i] = random.Next(501);
        
        int numberBigger = numbers[i] + 10;
        int numberSmaller = numbers[i] - 5;
        total += numbers[i];
        int number = int.Parse(numberBox.Text);

        if (number > numbers[i])
        {
            text += $"Element {i} = {numberBigger} \n";
        }
        else
        {
            text +=  $"Element {i} = {numberSmaller} \n";
        }
        printLabel.Text = text;
    }
}
```

The solution here is to add text to a variable in each loop combined by a new line `\n`. Another solution is to append the text to a c# list. Then join the list with a new line to get a multi-lines string.